# curl_exec PHP fatal error after random amount of time

Tags: php, curl, libcurl, fatal-error

I have a table with around 20000 with unprocessed Youtube posts.
This table is automatically filled using a cronjob which does work fine.
Now I have a code, which is supposed to only quit when all posts have been processed.

To do this, I have to fetch additional information from youtube using curl.
The code I have is running fine, but after a random amount of time/ posts, I get a fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   /home/local/domains/domain.com/private/include/classes/Youtube.php on
>   line 183

This is the code:

```
public function api_get($url, $params)
    {
        error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
        //set the youtube key
        $params["key"] = $this->youtube_key;

        //boilerplates for CURL
        $tuCurl = curl_init();
        error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
        curl_setopt_array($tuCurl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url . (strpos($url, "?") === false ? "?" : "") . http_build_query($params),
            CURLOPT_PORT => strpos($url, "https") === false ? 80 : 443,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => true,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
            CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS => false // only for debugging purposes
        ));
        error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
        $tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl);
        error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
        if (curl_errno($tuCurl)) {
            $curlError = curl_error($tuCurl);
            error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
            curl_close($tuCurl);
            error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
            throw new Elision("[#505011] "._("Curl Error:")." ". $curlError);
        }
        error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
        curl_close($tuCurl);
        error_log(__FILE__."::".__LINE__." - ".date("U"), 0);
        return $tuData;
    }
```

I used `error_log` to find out where my problem was, when I run this code using SSH, I get this (I only display the last few lines):

> /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::35
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::37
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::45
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::47
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::49
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::51
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::56
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::18
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::20
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::22
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::24
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::26
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::28
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::31
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::33
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::163
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::169
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::182
>   - 1426757941
>         % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                        Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>       102  1131  102  1131    0     0   4238      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15080
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::184
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::192
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::194
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::35
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::37
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::45
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::47
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::49
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::51
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::56
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::18
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::20
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::22
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::24
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::26
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::28
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::31
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/socket/youtube_parsing.php::33
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::163
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::169
>   - 1426757941
>       /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php::182
>   - 1426757941
>       PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/local/domains/localthisday.nl/private/include/classes/Youtube.php
>   on line 183

As you can see, the same code is running fine, but the next time, it doesn't run and creates a fatal error.
When I rerun the script, it also works for a random amount of time, and then crashes again so it can't be the input url.

Any ideas how to solve this problem to I don't get the fatal error?

Edit:
I forgot to add:
The function api_get is in the class `Youtube.php`.
I run this code from a file called `youtube_parsing.php`.
In `youtube_parsing.php` I have this to avoid the execution limit:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
```

Comment: It's probably a network latency issue. Have you tried increasing this setting in your curl code? `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30` You could also try increasing the PHP execution time limit with `set_time_limit()`

Comment: I've tried it a various values, but I don't really care about if the curl fails or not, I just want to code to continue instead of getting a fatal error which stops everything.

Comment: What is line 183 of Youtube.php? It looks like it has a PHP max time limit somewhere, which it's hitting before it hits the curl limit. But it's odd that you have avoided the execution limit anyway.

Comment: If you're doing a foreach in youtube_parsing then try putting set_time_limit(0) at the top of the loop so that it resets the time limit each time.

Comment: @gazareth, line 183 is nothing more than the `curl_exec`. I placed the `set_time_limit` in the foreach loop. I think it's not really a nice way to do this and it would be nicer to put it on top, but it seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the maximum possible  [execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php) in the php.ini.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it to my post, I've added it now.

Comment: set_time_limit(0) is not working when php is running in safe mode.